# Submit Dynamically generated inputs to SQL

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, dynamic, for-loop

I have a Java Script dynamically creating rows in a table when a contact is added.  Each contact added I want to submit them to a cell in a sql database.  I have no issues submitting the first contact but i need to use a loop (maybe a for loop?) to submit all of the contacts added to the dynamically created rows in the table.  I am very new to the C# community and looking for a little help on how to do this.

When the rows are created via Java Script I also have it creating an input with a 'name' value, this name value is what is used to submit to the cell in the database.

Thanks in advance

Code is below:

JavaScript

```
function flNames() {

var rowID = parseInt(document.getElementById("ContactsRowCount").value, 10);
rowID++;

if (currentRow > 0) {
    saveEdits();
} else {
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var sHtml = "<tr id='row" + rowID + "'>" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wlb' id=\"FirstN" + rowID + "\">" + firstName + "</td><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + firstName + "\" name=\"cFirst\" />" +
    "<td class='tblStyle68wl' id=\"LastN" + rowID + "\">" + lastName + "</td><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + lastName + "\" name=\"cLast\" />" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wl' ><button type='button' class='XsmallButtons' onclick='editRow(" + rowID + ")'>Edit</button></td>" +
        "<td class='tblStyle68wlb' ><button type='button' class='XsmallButtons' onclick='deleteRow(" + rowID + ")'>Delete</button></td>" +
        "</tr>";

    $("#dynamicTableTesting").append(sHtml);
    newRow++;

    document.getElementById("ContactsRowCount").value = rowID;

    $("#firstName, #lastName").val("");
}
}
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFormData();
    }
    private void GetFormData()
    {
        string dynamicFirstName = Request.Form["cFirst"];
        string dynamicLastName = Request.Form["cLast"];
        string tableContactID = Request.Form[""];
        string sql = @"
            INSERT INTO
                tableContactData
                    (
                         fName
                        ,lName
                    )
            VALUES
                (
                     @cFirst
                    ,@cLast
                );
            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        ";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cFirst", dynamicFirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cLast", dynamicLastName);

            conn.Open();
            tableContactID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            conn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Adding multiple contacts causes the data to submit to the same cell in the database and i assume the cause of that is the duplicated name value in the javascript inputs.  I not sure if a for-loop would work due to the fact that the amount of times it would loop would be unknown (user can add as many as they wish).

Comment: Why would I need ajax for this?   I just used a for-loop, ajax has no benefit to this at all!